Calling TikZ code (speedometer) several time to plot the same graph multiple time
I wonder if there is a way to encapsulate the following tikz code in a function so that I can repeat that diagram several times on the same page. I wanted to be able to redraw the following chart index several times while changing the location name and index values (\locationName and \myindex). Thanks

\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
%https://latexdraw.com/how-to-write-a-text-along-path-using-tikz-speedometer-case/
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1,transform shape,font=\large]
% Static part
% (angle : r )
\draw[draw=white,fill=red!50,thick] (0:2) -- (0:3.5) arc(0:45:3.5) -- (45:2) arc(45:0:2) -- cycle ;
\draw[draw=white,fill=orange!50,thick] (90:2cm)-- (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5) -- (45:2cm) arc (45:90:2);
\draw[draw=white,fill=yellow!50,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5) -- (90:2cm) arc (90:135:2);
\draw[draw=white,fill=green!50,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:180:3.5) -- (180:2cm) arc (180:135:2);

\def\locationName{location1}
%Labels
\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\Large\bfseries\sffamily|\locationName},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.0cm},
            decorate] (-2,-1) -- (2,-1); 

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={1-3},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (180:3.5cm) arc (180:135:3.5); 

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\small|Low},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (180:2.5cm) arc (180:135:2.5); 

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={4-6},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5);

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\small| Moderate},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (135:2.5cm) arc (135:90:2.5);
 
\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={7-10},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5);

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\small| High},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (90:2.5cm) arc (90:45:2.5);
 
\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={$>$10},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (45:3.5cm) arc (45:0:3.5);

\draw[decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\footnotesize| Very High},
            text align={center},
            raise=0.2cm},
            decorate] (45:2.5cm) arc (45:0:2.5);
 
% Speedometer needle

% converting quality air index into angle.
\def\myindex{12};
\ifnum\myindex<7 
% here we have 6 slices : 90 / 6 =15
\newcommand{\myangle}{180-\myindex*15}
% here we have 4 slices from 7 to 10 so 
% I divided 45/4 = 11.2 
\else\ifnum\myindex<14 
\newcommand{\myangle}{90-((\myindex+1)*12.2-90)}
\else
\newcommand{\myangle}{0}
\fi
\fi


\fill[black!70,rotate=\myangle] (0,0.2)--(0:2.75) -- (0,-0.2)--cycle;
\fill [black!70](0,0) circle (0.4cm);
\fill [white](0,0) circle (0.15cm);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The concept you need is called pics in TikZ.

Here is an option using code nesting through definitions, In this case I have used the code based on this post; To make it dynamic to the number of ranges, I used a counter that allows me to draw each segment, then an arrangement to use shadings by remembering the color data in a for environment, to shade to the last iteration color, finally a simple calculation so that I can specify the value that is placed, always and when the ranks are proportionally distributed. If the ranges are not desired in proportion to the segments, it is a matter of case mapping just as you implemented it for the 4 range case.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,backgrounds,shadings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        %Variables: 1:Position 2:Radio 3:Text adjusting 4: Data array {range text/zone text/colour} 5: Place 6: Value 7:Max Value
        \def\ColorWeel(#1)[#2][#3]#4#5#6#7{%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}] 
                \edef\Mycount{0}%Variable to get the number of entries in the array
                \foreach \element in {#4}{%For each element
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Mycount+1)}%increase in one unit the last value of \Mycount
                    \xdef\Mycount{\pgfmathresult}%Refresh the  \Mycount value
                }%\Mycount get the value of the number of elements in given by #4 array input.
                \pgfmathparse{180/\Mycount)}%Using the value of the number of inputs in the array
                \edef\Angle{\pgfmathresult}%Get the size of the angle sector for some range of valuis in the Gauje
                \foreach \Stext/\Mtext/\color [count=\i from 0, remember=\color as \kolor] in {#4}{
                    \def\Mypath{(180-\Angle*\i:#2) 
                        arc (180-\Angle*\i:180-\Angle*\i-\Angle:#2) 
                        -- (180-\Angle*\i-\Angle:#2*0.55)
                        arc (180-\Angle*\i-\Angle:180-\Angle*\i:#2*0.55)
                        -- cycle;}
                    \draw[draw=white,thick]\Mypath
                    \path[decoration={text along path,text={|\small|\Stext},text align=center},decorate]
                    (180-\Angle*\i:#2*1.05) arc (180-\Angle*\i:180-\Angle*\i-\Angle:#2*1.05); 
                    \path[decoration={text along path,text={|\small|\Mtext},text align=center},decorate]
                    (180-\Angle*\i:#2*#3) arc (180-\Angle*\i:180-\Angle*\i-\Angle:#2*#3);
                    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                        \ifnum\i=0
                            \shade[
                                bottom color=\color,
                                top color=\color!60!black,
                                shading angle=180-\Angle*\i-\Angle]\Mypath
                        \else
                            \shade[
                                bottom color=\color,
                                top color=\kolor,
                                shading angle=160-\Angle*\i]\Mypath;
                        \fi 
                    \end{scope}
                }
                
                \pgfmathparse{180-((180-\Angle)/#7*#6)}
                %\xdef\Value{\pgfmathresult} % by Nice cfr observation
                \fill[black!70,rotate=\pgfmathresult] (90:#2*0.05)--(0:#2*0.65) -- (-90:#2*0.05)--cycle;
                \fill [black!70](0,0) circle (#2*0.12);
                \fill [white](0,0) circle (#2*0.05);
                \draw(-90:#2*0.25) node[font=\bfseries] {#5};
                \draw(-90:#2*0.4) node[font=\bfseries] {#6};
                    
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        
        \ColorWeel(0,0)[2cm][0.72]{
            1-8/Bad/cyan,
            8-16/Good/green,
            $>$16/Excellent/orange%
        }{Quality}{8.5}{15}
    
        \ColorWeel(8,0)[3.5cm][0.77]{
            1-4/Low/green,
            4-8/Moderate/yellow,
            8-12/High/orange,
            $>$12/Very High/red%
        }{Location 1}{3.2}{12}
    
        \ColorWeel(16,0)[3.5cm][0.77]{
            1-10/Lvl-1/blue,
            10-20/Lvl-2/cyan,
            20-30/Lvl-3/green,
            30-40/Lvl-4/yellow,
            40-50/Lvl-5/orange,
            50-60/Lvl-6/red,
            $>$60/Lvl-7/red!50!black%
        }{Level}{45}{60}
    
        \ColorWeel(0,-6)[3.5cm][0.77]{
            1-3/Low/green,
            4-6/Moderate/yellow,
            7-10/High/orange,
            $>$10/Very High/red%
        }{Location 2}{7.5}{10}
    
        \ColorWeel(8,-6)[3.5cm][0.77]{
            1-3/Low/green,
            4-6/Moderate/yellow,
            7-10/High/orange,
            $>$10/Very High/red%
        }{Location 3}{11}{10}
    
        \ColorWeel(16,-6)[3.5cm][0.77]{
            1-3/Low/green,
            4-6/Moderate/yellow,
            7-10/High/orange,
            $>$10/Very High/red%
        }{Location 4}{5}{10}
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


More than wonderful!

Very nice! But I wouldn't do \xdef\Value. Isn't \edef enough? Or use \newcommand in the preamble to make sure.

@cfr Thanks for the observation, I honestly use \xdef only for practicality when using it within iterations and conditionals where sometimes nothing happens when you only use \edef, I wanted to use it to implement the non-proportional ranges and be able to visualize the variable in those places but recess time was ending, I'll read more about it, so those 2 lines can be skipped by simply using rotate=\pgfmathresult.

If you use \newcommand first, you will get an error if there's a conflict. Or you could use a name less likely to clash with anything. \xdef\jlValue is much less likely to overwrite anything than \xdef\Value ;).

You could use a pic and, if you need more flexibility, you might want to do that. However text decorations can take a very long time to compile and, while I highly recommend an externalisation solution such as memoize, reducing the compilation burden doesn't hurt.
The following splits the code into a section which draws the base speedometer and a section which draws the needle and adds the location. This means the former can be saved in a box and reused. A new command is then defined \speedometer which takes two arguments: the first is the location and the second is the air quality.
The code also corrects the bounding box of the base speedometer, since the original code didn't take account of the text decorations and PGF doesn't seem to keep track of those.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\newsavebox\speedometerbox
\newcommand\myangle{}
\newlength\tmpaht
\tikzset{%
  speedo/.style={font=\large}
}
%https://latexdraw.com/how-to-write-a-text-along-path-using-tikz-speedometer-case/
% adjusted: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717396/
\sbox\speedometerbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture} [speedo]
    % Static part
    % (angle : r )
    \draw[draw=white,fill=red!50,thick] (0:2) -- (0:3.5) arc(0:45:3.5) -- (45:2) arc(45:0:2) -- cycle ;
    \draw[draw=white,fill=orange!50,thick] (90:2cm)-- (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5) -- (45:2cm) arc (45:90:2);
    \draw[draw=white,fill=yellow!50,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5) -- (90:2cm) arc (90:135:2);
    \draw[draw=white,fill=green!50,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:180:3.5) -- (180:2cm) arc (180:135:2);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={1-3},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (180:3.5cm) arc (180:135:3.5); 
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={|\small|Low},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (180:2.5cm) arc (180:135:2.5); 
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={4-6},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={|\small| Moderate},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (135:2.5cm) arc (135:90:2.5);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={7-10},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={|\small| High},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (90:2.5cm) arc (90:45:2.5);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={$>$10},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (45:3.5cm) arc (45:0:3.5);
    
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={|\footnotesize| Very High},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.2cm},
    decorate] (45:2.5cm) arc (45:0:2.5);
    
    \pgfmathsetlength \tmpaht {height("$1234567890$")+2mm}
    \path   (current bounding box.north west) coordinate (a)    ++(-\tmpaht,\tmpaht) coordinate (b) -| (current bounding box.south east)  ++(\tmpaht,0pt) -| (b);
    
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \speedometer { mm }
{% #1 location #2 index 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[speedo]
    \node [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,line width=0pt,anchor=base] {\usebox{\speedometerbox}};
    %Labels
    \draw[decoration={
      text along path,
      text={|\Large\bfseries\sffamily|#1},
      text align={center},
      raise=0.0cm},
    decorate] (-2,-1) -- (2,-1); 
    
    % Speedometer needle
    
    % converting quality air index into angle.
    \def\myindex{#2}
    \ifnum\myindex<7 
      % here we have 6 slices : 90 / 6 =15
      \renewcommand{\myangle}{180-\myindex*15}
      % here we have 4 slices from 7 to 10 so 
      % I divided 45/4 = 11.2 
    \else
      \ifnum\myindex<14 
        \renewcommand{\myangle}{90-((\myindex+1)*12.2-90)}
      \else
        \renewcommand{\myangle}{0}
      \fi
    \fi
    
    \fill[black!70,rotate=\myangle] (0,0.2)--(0:2.75) -- (0,-0.2)--cycle;
    \fill [black!70](0,0) circle (0.4cm);
    \fill [white](0,0) circle (0.15cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\speedometer{Merseyside}{3}

\speedometer{Cotswolds}{7}

\speedometer{Arctic}{12}
\end{document}

I haven't been able to add useful images due to an Okular-on-X bug, but I'm going to try something different in a minute. If a picture appears, it worked; if not, I got stuck.
Not brilliant, but not as awful as Okular's:

Produced with pdfcrop <filename>.pdf <filename>-c.pdf ; convert <filename>-c.pdf <filename>-c.png. I probably need to fiddle with the options (and kill the page numbers).
But a bit more hassle than cut-and-paste!

Is this a known okukar bug?

@Simd Yes. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=483204.
